# Instances of sparse covariance matrices

Tags: covariance, large-data, sparse

I am trying to find large datasets with inherently sparse covariance matrices, to be tested with our algorithm. Basically, we will take the sample covariance matrix and enforce some structured sparsity (such as banding or hard thresholding) and adjusting it back to a positive semidefinite matrix.

The weird thing is that I am having the hardest time finding real data that actually has sparse covariance! I think the place to look is something with a band pattern, such as with shifted time series, but I can't think of the right application for this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Either abstract concepts or links to data are appreciated; I'm getting good at finding data once I know what application I'm targeting but I'm blanking out now on what application to use!

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you mean sparse *inverse* covariance matrices? I think in general it will be hard to find sparse covariance matrices unless the noise/error is really tiny.

Comment: That is useful information for me! I was hoping to find maybe something that propagates through time for a banded pattern, like let's say traffic data, but so far no luck; this could be why. Ok let's say sparse inverse covariance matrix. What might work well for that? Thanks for your input!

Comment: Also this may seem like a stupid question but is a sample inverse covariance matrix calculated by inverting a sample covariance matrix? Or is there a more preferred way? (I'm guessing that would be terribly numerically unstable...)

Comment: Just to clarify, not saying that sparse covariance is impossible, just that for all the data I see (biological data), the high degree of correlation means even if the "true" signal is sparse you get non-sparse covariance. To infer sparse inverse covariance from non-sparse covariance is a statistical problem in itself. Like you say, simple inversion can be problematic depending on the condition number, L2-penalized inversion is better but not sparse, but L1-penalized inversion (graphical lasso) can give you sparse inverse covariance.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense! Ok, I think I should stick to sparse (not inverse) covariance matrices then. To clarify, when you say the covariance is non-sparse, is that a result of the number of samples being much smaller than the number of variables? I think that may actually be the motivation behind hard-thresholding covariance matrices, which I had suspected kept on failing for me because the true covariance was not actually sparse. But it would be encouraging if in, say, gene expression data, the "true" covariance matrix is expected to be sparse!

Comment: Yes time series or spatial data *that has already been detrended* are good bets, as are spatially clustered data (e.g. students within the same school may be correlated, but should be uncorrelated between schools).

Comment: Hmm, good point! I think I'll go back to temperature data over time. I almost had it working but it was too correlated because of seasonal variations... I think I need a better way of detrending  than just subtracting the mean (the variance is also seasonal). Maybe a high pass filter, or maybe that would be overkill? Anyway thanks, this gives me a lot to think about!

Comment: This was a long time ago but I think covariance and precision are both sparse together. I can't remember where I saw this but have a look around. Definitely noise has nothing to do with it unless you mean dependent "correlated" noise.

Comment: Hi @mathtick, if $C$ (covariance) is sparse, $C^{-1}$ (precision) is not necessarily sparse (or vice versa). Do you  mean that there are applications where they usually are sparse? And the noise has to do with sample vs real covariance matrices; sample covariance matrices are usually not sparse, even if the real one is. But maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes, real covariance vs sample is what I was getting at. And I'm not sure about the sparsity cov vs precision ... should find a proof. If $C = U U^T + \text{diag}(D)$ where $U$ is sparse for example. Try it wth ```B = scipy.sparse.random(30, 30); np.linalg.inv(B.dot(B.T).todense() + np.diag(np.ones(30)))```

Comment: So I'm guessing there is some sparsity scale at which the probability that both covariance and precision are sparse. If the probability of two components being independent is high ... something like that. Haven't found an explicit statement yet.

Comment: Hmm, ok, by Woodbury inversion lemma, if your matrix is so sparse that $B$ in fact doesn't even have a nonzero in each row, the inverse will be sparse in the offdiagonals corresponding to those 0 blocks. So it does make sense that if $U$ is pretty skinny and mostly sparse, you would expect $C^{-1}$ to be sparse.